# PHP only printing 1st line of MySQL textfield with multiple lines. Using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to print the result of a mysqli query in PHP but it is only displaying the first line and there are multiple lines in the text field. Can you help me know what command I need to use?

Thank you.

```
result = $mysqli->query("SELECT someData FROM someTable WHERE id='Bob' AND group='TheGroup'"); 
$num_rows = $result->num_rows; 
printf($num_rows." "); 
if ($num_rows == 1) { 
    printf("In if..."); 
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) { 
        printf("%s", $row[0]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: how are you displaying the text (html element wise)?

Comment: It's actually a java program that calls the script. It uses Buffered Reader and InputStreamReader to read whatever is printed out.

Comment: Could you add some extra code, please? Could we see the part where you run the query and assign $num_rows?

Comment: I'm not able to format this well, but here you go! $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT someData FROM someTable WHERE id='Bob' AND group='TheGroup'");

$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
printf($num_rows." ");

if ($num_rows == 1) {
    printf("In if...");
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        printf("%s", $row[0]);
    }

Comment: do you get different results by replacing printf with `echo $row[0]`

Comment: No, same results. It prints the first line of the text field, and then stops.

Comment: @bstrong - I've edited the code into your question. Why do you have a while loop, when your code is only ever going to return one row?

Comment: and you have confirmed that the database contains all of the text... didn't get truncated on the input side

Comment: Yes, I have checked the textfield. It is basically stopping when it gets to a newline.

Comment: @bstrong - if you do a var_dump($row[0]), do you see all the contents? How are you debugging this, by the way - are you running it directly, or through your Java code?

Comment: I haven't tried the var_dump, but I realized that it probably is in the java code that I'm running it through. I'm working on debugging that.

Comment: @bstrong - you should add that as an answer, and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic:

```
if ($num_rows == 1) {}
```

the control will only go to this part of the code if you are getting only one row back from the database. So the part where you display all the rows never gets executed.

This one should work just fine:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
    printf("%s", $row[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: why is that a problem?

Comment: The input I am using only allows one return. I know it is getting to that part because it prints other things that I put in the if statement (I took them out to be concise).

Comment: It's not a problem per say but the answer is based on the assumption that the code is checking for how many rows are being returned from the database. It then displays all the rows only when 1 row is being returned so those 2 are mutually exclusive conditions when the query returns more than one row.